# Gridview making a column invisable

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hi I have a grid view which is dynamically generated via C# using a DataSet. 
I'm passing a row ID field (from the database) to the grid view, as this is required when a user clicks to edit a records. However I don't want the user to be able to view the column.
I have tried the following but it doesn’t seem to work? Could anyone suggest a way to hide the column or a better way of attaching the information to the grid view row so it can be used at a later stage.
c#

```
        DataColumn ColImplantCustomerDetailsID = new DataColumn();
        ColImplantCustomerDetailsID.ColumnName = "Implant ID";
        ColImplantCustomerDetailsID.DataType = typeof(int);
        ColImplantCustomerDetailsID.Visable = false; <-- visable doens't work here.
```

asp.net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DataColumn doesn't have a 'Visable' property. Heck, it doesn't have a 'Visible' property either.

Use this before you bind

```
gridviewNameHere.Columns[index].Visible = false;
```

You can make it visible again on one of your event handlers.

Answer (score 4):

Another option, rather than hiding the column, is to use the `DataKeyNames` property of the GridView to store the name of the ID field.  You can then use `myGridView.SelectedValue` to retrieve the selected ID.

Comment: Thanks, I have looked into doing it that way. I couldn't quite get my head around it but I might have to get it another look.

Answer (score 2):

Use the index of the column to hide it when you initialize it...

```
grid.Columns[index].Visible = false;
```

I actually hide a few things as you are suggesting, example - database status names for that row that can be used in code that the user does not need to see.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing GridView Invisible Columns

http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/178_Access_GridView_Invisible_Columns.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In the `OnRowDataBound` event of the `GridView` component:

```
// c# 
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    int index = 0; // put the index of the column you need hide.
    e.Row.Cells[index].Visible = false;  
}
```